# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '__expo_module_name__' of undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native, component, expo

```
ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property '__expo_module_name__' of undefined, js engine: hermes
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered.
```

He actualizado un proyecto de Expo creado en 2021 y tenia olvidado.

Me enfrente a varios problemas como Firebase, Babel, etc. los cuales he corregido. Pero ahora me encuentro con uno que no puedo corregir:

```
iOS Bundled 19606ms (node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js)
 WARN  The native view manager required by name (ExpoAdsAdMobBannerView) from NativeViewManagerAdapter isn't exported by expo-modules-core. Views of this type may not render correctly. Exported view managers: [ExpoAppleAuthentication, ExpoCamera, ExpoCameraNext, ExpoVideo, ExpoClipboard, ExponentGLView, ExpoImage, ExpoBlurView, ExpoLinearGradient, ExpoVideoView, ExpoBarCodeScanner].
 ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property '__expo_module_name__' of undefined, js engine: hermes
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes
info Opening /app/node_modules/expo-modules-core/build/EventEmitter.js
```

Busque soluciones en internet, pero no logro corregirlo.

El simulador muestra error que no sé cómo interpretar en esta línea del archivo

```
/node_modules/expo-modules-core/build/EventEmitter.js
nativeModule.addListener = (...args) =&gt; NativeModules.EXReactNativeEventEmitter.addProxiedListener(nativeModule.__expo_module_name__, ...args);
```

el error lo muestran los argumentos `(...args)`

Mostraré mi package.json, espero alguien haya visto esto alguna vez y pueda ayudarme.

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/toolbar-android": "^0.2.1",
    "accordion-collapse-react-native": "^1.1.1",
    "asset": "^0.4.13",
    "expo": "^50.0.6",
    "expo-ads-admob": "~13.0.0",
    "expo-app-loading": "^2.1.1",
    "expo-av": "~13.10.5",
    "expo-facebook": "~12.2.0",
    "expo-font": "~11.10.2",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~12.7.1",
    "firebase": "10.8.0",
    "moment": "^2.30.1",
    "native-base": "3.4.28",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.73.4",
    "react-native-device-detection": "^0.2.1",
    "react-native-easy-grid": "^0.2.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.14.0",
    "react-native-hr-component": "^2.0.3",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-modalbox": "^2.0.2",
    "react-native-netinfo": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.6.2",
    "react-native-render-html": "^6.3.4",
    "react-native-root-toast": "^3.5.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.8.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-view": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.29.0",
    "react-native-star-rating": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-svg": "14.1.0",
    "react-native-swiper-flatlist": "^3.2.3",
    "react-native-timeago": "^0.5.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "10.0.3",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6",
    "react-native-webview": "13.6.4",
    "react-navigation": "^4.3.7",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.4.11",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.3.11",
    "tcomb-form-native": "^0.6.20"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "babel-preset-expo": "^10.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Presta atención a este mensaje: **Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder.**, verifica que el proyecto está bien configurado y que las carpetas y la estructura general sean consistentes.

Comment: Otra cosa que me llama la atención está en tu `package.json`, la entrada "main" que pone: `"main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js"` No logro comprender porqué usarías ese punto de entrada desde `node_modules`.

Comment: Gracias por tus apreciaciones. El proyecto es de hace unos años y ralmente estoy desorientado. Por una enfermedad he perdido facultades y estoy un poco perdido. El proyecto esta en las tiendas de aplicaciones, pero debido a mi enfermedad, eta todo desatendido y en breve eliminaran esta aplicaciones. Por ello acudi aqui, para tratar de encontrar soluciones